# regular expression for below pattern

Tags: ruby

I need a regular expression that matches this text:

```
894975||0||Lever 2000 Anti-Bacterial Bar Soap ||Health & Spa/Personal Care/Body Care/Soap
```

I want to search the text, and, after two sets of pipes, match "Bar Soap".

If the words are not in order then it's not matching.
My regex is:

```
/^(?:\d+\|\|).?\|\|[^|]*?(Bar[^|]*? Soap)/i
```

This is not matching when "soap" comes first and "bar" second.

Comment: In a comment below you say you could get different input values. We need to see more examples in order to help you. Without them any attempt to answer is shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample data looks like a standard pipe-delimited (`'|'`) file you'd see from database extracts. It's common to see fields with a null value show up as `||` in the output.

Rather than try to parse it using a regex, it's usually handled by splitting on the pipes, or by treating it as a CSV record with a pipe instead of comma as the column-separator. Splitting on double-pipes (`||`) will fail if you get a record where the field actually has content.

Here's two different samples showing how I'd do it. The first is splitting on `|` into fields.

```
text = '894975||0||Lever 2000 Anti-Bacterial Bar Soap ||Health & Spa/Personal Care/Body Care/Soap'
fields = text.split('|')
```

`fields` at this point looks like:

```
[
    [0] "894975",
    [1] "",
    [2] "0",
    [3] "",
    [4] "Lever 2000 Anti-Bacterial Bar Soap ",
    [5] "",
    [6] "Health & Spa/Personal Care/Body Care/Soap"
]
```

Grabbing the fifth field retrieves the product:

```
product = fields[4]
=> "Lever 2000 Anti-Bacterial Bar Soap"
```

A second way to do this is to treat the content as a CSV file with `|` delimiters:

```
require 'csv'

text = <<EOT
894975||0||Lever 2000 Anti-Bacterial Bar Soap ||Health & Spa/Personal Care/Body Care/Soap
EOT

CSV.parse(text, :col_sep => '|') do |row|
  puts row[4]
end

=> "Lever 2000 Anti-Bacterial Bar Soap"
```

The advantage of doing it using CSV is it's possible to find a `|` character in text, and CSV will handle decoding embedded pipes correctly.

Because there's only one sample input line, this solution can't be more thorough.

Answer (score 2):

First, split the line into elements:

```
product = str.split(/\|\|/)[2]
```

Then, try check if it includes "bar" and "soap":

```
puts "match" if product =~ /bar/i and product =~ /soap/i
puts "match" if product =~ /bar.*soap|soap.*bar/i
puts "match" if product =~ /(?=.*bar)(?=.*soap)/i
```

[ADDED]

If you want to use variable match_terms, try this:

```
re = match_terms.split(/,/).map { |t| "(?=.*#{Regexp::quote t})" }.join ""
puts "match" if product =~ /#{re}/i
```

or

```
terms = match_terms.upcase.split(/,/)
puts "match" if terms.select { |t| product.upcase.include? t }.size == terms.size
```

Comment: but everytime i wont get 2 words only..I may get more than 2 also..In that case what can i do?

Comment: /^(?:\d+\|\|).?\|\|[^|]*?(#{match_terms.split(",").join("[^|]*?")})/i

Here in match_terms i may get more than two words also..